# Azure On-Premises Gateway with SSASaaS

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssas

I currently have two windows VMs on azure, both running SQL server 2016. One is for our development environment and one is for production.

I also have two instances of SSASaaS on Azure for Dev and production.

My question is, I'm having trouble understanding how to set up the On-premises gateway correctly for this environment. Do I need an on-prem gateway on each? Since I need access to two different servers.

Comment: wth is `SSASaaS`?

Comment: As long as there is network connectivity between SSAS and SQL Server (which I assume is the source), then you don't need an on prem gateway.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're also going to have a dev Azure Analysis Services instance and production Analysis Services instance. Then, you'll need to install two on-prem gateways. One on your dev machine and one for your production machine.

Then you have to create two Azure On-premises Data Gateway services, one for your dev Gateway and connect it to your dev AAS instance, and one for your prod gateway and connect it to your production AAS instance.